# Solr - return only search terms in spellcheck collation

Tags: solr

Evening All!
This is my first time posting to stackoverflow, which means it was the first time I couldn't find the answer on stackoverflow.

On a solr instance, I'm passing a query "name:Buttrfly AND description:Buttrfly".

If I'm including spellcheck, and it provides a collated suggestion, it will include the field names

```
<str name="collation">name:Butterfly AND description:Butterfly</str>
```

Is there a switch I can use to instruct solr to only return the actual query term as the collation? e.g.

```
<str name="collation">Butterfly</str>
```

I can easily parse this out:

```
preg_replace('/name:/','',array_shift( explode(' AND ',$this->spellCheckResult) ) );
```

But it would surprise me if Solr does not have this ability, as it already knows what the actual query terms are.  BTW, using Solr 4.0

Thanks!